# Opacity with onclick, onmousedown & onmouseup

Tags: html, timer, toggle, image, opacity

I am a newbie to javascript programming, but am making progress! I am developing a web app in house for children with autism, for touch screen browsers (55" touch screen PCs and Nexus 7 tablets). We will only use Firefox as it appears most compatible. The children will click on image "buttons" to make choices and to communicate their needs. The buttons need to give visual feedback when touched. I have solved this by using the active state in CSS:

```
img { opacity:1.0 };
img:active { opacity:0.4 };
```

This works fine. Hover is no good for use on touch screens. I also have a need for some images to be made invisible but to remain where they are, and to toggle on and off on a long press. For this I have found a toggle function and a timer function and combined them.

JAVASCRIPT (in `<head>` of page):

```
var t
function tog_vis(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.opacity == 1 )
      e.style.opacity = 0 ;
   else
      e.style.opacity = 1 ;
```

HTML:

```
<img id="myimg" onclick="DoSomething();" onmousedown="t=setTimeout(function(){ tog_vis('myimg'); }, 1500);" onmouseup="clearTimeout(t);" src="images/img1.png">
```

Problem is the active state gets taken over by the onmousedown and onmouseup events (I have read that this is because they are both part of the click event - makes sense!), and I am guessing that the onclick event may also mess things up further.

Expected/Desired behaviour:

1.On a normal click, the image changes opacity to 0.4, and when released returns to 1, then completes the onclick request.

2.On a long click, the image opacity goes to 0, and on a second long click the opacity returns to 1, with NO onclick event.

The app will eventually have @ 100 similar images that must perform the first behaviour, whilst the second behaviour will only be needed on @ 10 buttons so I could happily code functions individually if necessary. I have also found that the 55" touchscreens (Windows 7) are not responding to the img:active CSS, so guessing these are relying on the touchdown and touchup events, whilst the tablets are very well behaved.

Any help here much appreciated.

Tim

Answer (score 1):

You could you css3 transitions and a little javascript for this use case. Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ce8J5/

Also you could realise the hover with javascript/jquery, just remove the hover css statement and define some addionatial css classes and add them via javascript.

E.g.

```
$("#element").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).addClass(".hover");
});

$("#element").mouseleave(function(){
$(this).removeClass(".hover");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll have to go and read up on css transitions! Copied your fiddle to an html file and can't get the 0.2 opacity to come up ? Also, can't use "hover" due to touchscreens.

Comment: Well I have nearly cracked it. Decided to use a second transparent image instead of going for opacity of 0. The only bit I can't for the life of me figure out is stopping the mouseup function call on the short click when returning from transparent. My code will show the mouseup() function. This is where the problem is. I don't want "tog-vis('mydiv')" to run when I "make" it the active code for the mouseup event, only for future mouseup events. How do I stop the code running at the time I replace the code? Here is all the html: [link](http://tsah.co.uk/tsah/boxes).

Comment: Short click will make black square appear and disappear(this is the "function", long click will make red box change to brown box. Brown box is just clickable, no action. Long click on brown box will return the red box. At this point you will see the black box either appear or disappear - this is what I need to stop, and only for this particular mouseup event. After that it needs to work as before.